# XSLT 1.0: Match only one of the two templates based on precedence

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, xslt-1.0, operator-precedence

XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name(.)='root']/*[local-name(.)='child1']" /> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name(.)='root']/*[local-name(.)='child2']/*[local-name()='anotherchild1']" /> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[local-name(.)='child1']">
     <!-- do something in template1 !-->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[local-name(.)='anotherchild1']" priority="0">
    <!-- do something in template2 !-->
</xsl:template>
```

Example:

```
<a:root>
   <b:child1>
     <d:grandchildOfChild1>
     </d:grandchildOfChild1>
   </b:child1>
   <c:child2>
     <d:anotherchild1>
       <d:grandchildOfAnotherChild1>
       </d:grandchildOfAnotherChild1>
     </d:anotherchild1>
   </c:child2>
</a:root>
```

Requirements:

- If only 'child1' is present, I want to do something with 'grandchildOfChild1'
- If only 'anotherchild1' is present, I want to do something with 'grandchildOfAnotherChild1'
- If 'child1' & 'anotherchild1' are present, I want only 'child1' template to take precedence and do something with 'grandchildOfChild1'.

The above XSL yields me the expected results for #1, #2, but if both are present, both the templates are matched and both the results are rendered. How do I make it to take only the first one?

Comment: To me the question isn't clear at all. I can see all the elements in your input, but your explanation is "conditional" on their presence. Can you rephrase it please.

Comment: I think the thing to do before trying to solve this is to learn how to use namespaces correctly. There are dozens of answers here on SO showing how to do that. I also agree that your question is completely unclear. Please show us a real-world example and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

> If only 'child1' is present, I want to do something with
>   'grandchildOfChild1'

Here's an example of template that matches `grandchildOfChild1` only when its parent `child1` has no siblings:

```
<xsl:template match="child1[count(../*) = 1]/grandchildOfChild1">
    <!-- do something with 'grandchildOfChild1' -->
</xsl:template>
```

You can do the same thing for your second requirement.

---

> If 'child1' & 'anotherchild1' are present, I want only 'child1'
>   template to take precedence and do something with
>   'grandchildOfChild1'.

This part is not clear. I *think* you want to have another template:

```
<xsl:template match="grandchildOfChild1">
    <!-- do something else with 'grandchildOfChild1' -->
</xsl:template>
```

This will kick into action whenever the more specific template above is inapplicable.

Comment: Thank you! My #3 requirement is to match only over the first template when both the elements are present in the incoming XML document. As an example, if 'child1' & 'anotherchild1' is present, I want the template matching 'child1' to take priority and only be matched. The template to match 'anotherchld1' should be ignored. Hope this is clear..

Comment: No, I am afraid it's not clear at all. You can have several templates matching `child1` and specify the conditions determining which one will be applied when. You cannot have a template matching  `child1` override a template matching `anotherchild1`.